# Google Play store security alert: "Your app(s) are using a WebView that is vulnerable to cross-app scripting"

Tags: webview, google-play, android-security

I have a hybrid app - a simple webview opens the website (single page angular website).

I got this security message from Google store:

Your app includes a WebView that is vulnerable to cross app scripting. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.
**Vulnerable classes:**
WebActivity->setWebView
**Cross-app Scripting**
Your app(s) are using a WebView that is vulnerable to cross-app scripting.To address this issue, follow the steps in this Google Help Center article (https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9084685).

I tried "you can set android:exported=false for the Activities in your Manifest." - this prevents the entire app to launch. When I open the app it doesn't do anything and show "App not found" message.

and I have `<meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing" android:value="true" />`  declared in the Manifest . Also have MinSdkVersion=19.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without details about your app, but as it seems that your WebView activity is required (is it the main activity?), you need to take option 2.

As pointed out in the article, increase targetSdk version, check any input that is evaluated from JavaScript, and disable file access from your WebView.

BTW, SafeBrowsing will flag phishing and malware websites, it is not directly related to cross-app scripting vulnerabilities.